# Como puedo imprimir colores en la terminal de Windows 10 "cmd" con colorama?

Tags: windows10, python-3.8, text-color

Estoy intentando imprimir en la terminal "cmd" un texto con color con la libreria colorama pero no me imprime el color solo me da esto:

> ←[31m←[46m←[1mIngresa tu nombre

Y el codigo es este:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
n = input(Fore.RED + Back.CYAN + Style.BRIGHT + "Ingresa tu nombre")
```

Pero cuando lo imprimo en mi editor de codigo si me sale con el color, me podrian ayudar no se que estoy haciendo mal.

> Estoy usando Python 3.8

Comment: Tal vez se deba a este [*issue*](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/265) reportado en el repositorio de Colorama. Saludos

Comment: Aunque probe con un script disitnto, hecho por otra persona que también usa colorama y ese si me corrio en la terminal con el color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví gente, solo deben hacer un 'cls' con os.system en Windows, y en Linux un 'clear', esto hace que el input salga con el color que asignamos, aunque creo que en Linux no le afecta el error del input, saludos...